# Ansible issue when trying to echo some stuff using variables

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible task when I try to generate a curl request part with an echo which will later on be used in the curl command. The task looks like the following:

```
  - name: Generate requestcode
shell: echo  '{ title: '{{get_hostname.stdout}}', key: '{{ssh_pu_key.stdout}}' }'
debug: msg: { title: '{get_hostname.stdout}'}
register: curl_request
```

The error I am seeing in when I try to run the code is the following:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/root/wifirush.yml': line 54, column 26, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - name: Generate requestcode
    shell: echo  '{ title: '{{get_hostname.stdout}}', key: '{{ssh_pu_key.stdout}}' }'
                         ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Any suggestion how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
shell: echo  "{ title{{ ":" }} '{{get_hostname.stdout}}', key {{ ":" }} '{{ssh_pu_key.stdout}}' }"
```

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: That worked. Thanks I did not know how to escape those columns.